# Why do we have "is not a Number" (isNan) functions?

Tags: numbers, floating-point, logic, ieee-754

Many languages have an isNaN() function. I am asking myself: why check for *not being a number*?

Is the reason purely logical or is it faster to check for *not a number* instead of *is a number*?

*Note* that this is a pure question of understanding. I know that I can negate isNaN() to achieve an isNumber() function for example.
However I am searching for a reason WHY we are checking for *not a number*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In computing, NaN (Not a Number) is a
>   value of numeric data type
>   representing an undefined or
>   unrepresentable value, especially in
>   floating-point calculations.

[Wiki Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Because Not a Number is a special case of an expression.

You can't just use 0 or -1 or something like that because those numbers already have meanings.

Not a Number means something went awry in a calculation and a valid number cannot be computed out of it.

It's on the same line of thinking as having `null`.  Sure, we could assign an arbitrary numerical value to mean `null` but it would be confusing and we'd hit all sorts of weird errors on corner cases.

Answer (score 3):

'Not a Number' is the result of specific floating point calculations. It's not about "hey, is this variable holding 120 or "abc"?'

Answer (score 2):

`isThisCaseExceptional` seems more reasonable to me than `isEverythingNormal` because I'm likely to write

```
possible_number = some_calculation();

if (inNaN(possible_number)) handle_the_surprise;

// .. keep going
```

instead of

```
possible_number = some_calculation();

if (inANumber(possible_number)) {

   // .. keep going 

} else {
   // handle the surprise
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The check is for whether it is not a number, because the assumption is that it is a number. NaN is the exceptional case when you're expecting a numeric value, so it makes sense to me that it is done this way. I'd rather check for isNaN infrequently than check if a value isNum frequently, after all.

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to report an error condition (mathematically undefined or outside of technical limits).

Answer (score 0):

Many languages have special representations if the result of a computation is not representable by a number, for example NaN and Inf. So isNaN() checks, if a result is actually a number or the special marker for NaN.

Answer (score 0):

NaNs are used for:

- Nonreal or undefined values.
- Error handling.  Initializing a variable with NaN allows you to test for NaN and make sure it has been set with a valid value.
- Objects that ignore a member or property.  For example, WPF uses NaN to represent the Width and Height of visual elements that do not define their own size.